Derivation of electronic states for a Chromium 3+ ion
I have been trying to find from scratch the electronic levels involved in a Ruby laser. I know that since we have a d3 ion we have a 4F ground term symbol and a 2G as first excited. In a octahedral field these should split according to irreducible representations of Oh group:

Now, i am having some trouble trying to assign these states to specific electronic configurations, such as (t2g)3 and (t2g)2 (eg)1. For example if I use the product table to compute t2g x t2g x t2g I get more states than the ones depicted in this table, which are the ones i am supposed to use:

So, I mainly have two questions,

How can one find the states in the second table, discarding the excess ones. I guess it has to do with spin , but i am not sure how to include that

How can one unambiguously say states belong to a specific configuration, for example saying that 4A2g 2Eg 2T1g 2T2g belong to (t2g)3 configuration ash shown here?



In principle, also the also the other configuration has 2T1g and 2T2g, please clarify this ambiguity.
Thank you for your time!

Cr$^{3+}$ ions are present effectively as an impurity in Al2O3 so consider these as free ions in an octahedral field. The allowed pumping (absorption) transition is from $^4A$ to both the $^4T$ levels ($^4T_2$ is lowest), then rapid intersystem crossing to doublet $ ^2E$ . This is spin forbidden to the ground state and the lowest of these levels is the lasing transition at 694.3 nm. You should use Hund's rule to sort level ordering and look up or calculate symmetry species of atomic orbitals in Oh symmetry, for example, F (L=3) transforms as $A_2+T_1+T_2$.
(To work out how F transforms you need to find an f orbital equation in terms of cartesian coordinates, i.e in x,y,z rather than in polar coordinates as often listed. Usefully Wikipedia gives a list of these although you can work them out. It turns out that they transform as a triple product such as $z^3, xyz, x(x^2-3y^2) $ etc. Next you have to work out how these functions transform in $O_h$ symmetry. You do this by looking at the effect each symmetry operation has on each triple product and then identifying the Mulliken label $A_1, E, T$ etc. The book 'Symmetry & Spectroscopy' by Harris & Bertolucci explains all of this.)
